# Why is the curses module not installing via pip?

Tags: python, windows, terminal, pip, curses

I have been trying to install the curses module using the command "pip install windows-curses" but it does not seem to be working and it errors out saying:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for windows-curses
```

[Edit: I am using python 3.10]

I installed the requests package after that using pip but that seems to install perfectly. So, pip is working correctly, just not the curses module. Is it a problem on my end or is this package actually not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the latest version of windows-curses is [2.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/2.2.0/) and it [provides](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/2.2.0/#files) wheels for Python 3.6-3.8 and no source code.

Most probably you use Python 3.9 or 3.10 (you should have indicated in the question). To use windows-curses you need to downgrade. You can also download wheels from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)

Comment: yes, i use python 3.10. Forgot to mention that 

Comment: Has anyone built a custom version of Windows-curses for Python 3.10 64bit?  I don't want to downgrade Python 3.10.  Is there a way to know when the official version is available?

Comment: @MKANET Did you try to follow links in my answer and look up the latest versions?

Comment: @Titan Yes I did.  They are still using version 2.2.0.  I'll have to keep checking those links.

Comment: @MKANET Well, wrong. At the 1st site (PyPI) there is version 2.3.1 with wheels for Python 3.6-3.11. At the 2nd site I see version 2.2.1 with wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.5-3.11.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry, I'm not very experienced with Python.  I found `curses‑2.2.1+utf8‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl` available for download in the second link.  If I have Python 3.10 (64 bit) for Windows... Do I execute the following command? `pip install c:\curses-2.2.1+utf8-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` after I download the wheel file?

Comment: @MKANET Yep, that is: `pip install \path\to\wheel`. Could be just `pip install .\wheel` for a wheel in the current directory.