# from _curses import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses

Tags: python-curses

This is the error I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\brook\python_practice\snake.py", line 1, in 
import curses
File "C:\Users\brook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\curses_*init*_.py", line 13, in 
from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

I tried pip install windows-curses and a few other things I found on stack overflow, nothing has worked.
I'm using VSCode.

Comment: This answers your question: [Why is the curses module not installing via pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985874/why-is-the-curses-module-not-installing-via-pip)